# Python - Faster way to access top-class variables

Tags: python, class

I'm currently programming a game in python. I have a main class (engine.py), and many subclasses. The main class has some important variables like the player. When I now am in a subclass, and want to access another variable or function, it often looks like this:

```
self.handleToEngine.player.playerObj.animationHandler.doSomething()
```

Is there a way to shorten this? I don't believe the performance is that good, and it's no clean code.

Comment: You may have to provide more details on your class hierarchy and the composition of the objects. This will help us to suggest on how to goa about refactoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute chain reflects your class structure, so of course you could refactor that if it makes sense.  Also, in Python 2.2 or later, you can use [`__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots) to improve access to member data, with some caveats.

Comment: I think I'm going to deal with this, even If I have to rewrite some structures ..

Answer (score 2):

Give it a local name (also saves lookup time):

```
f = self.handleToEngine.player.playerObj.animationHandler.doSomething
f ()
```

Comment: This is only usefull if I have multiple calls on this function, but I'm looking for something I could get a faster access with ..

Comment: @TobSpr Faster access during execution time?

Comment: Yeah, + less code to access ... but I believe there's no real solution